# Knockout JS - lost binding after manipulating DOM

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am lost in the next situation.

I am using Knockoutjs (v3.4.2). I have this viewmodel:

```
var vm = {
    items: ko.observableArray([
    { label: "test" },
    { label: "test2" },
    { label: "test3" },
    { label: "test4" }
  ])
};
```

And this template:

```
<div id="vm">

  <ul data-bind="foreach: items, sortable">
    <li data-bind="text: label"></li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

My binding:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.sortable = {
  init: function(el) {
    let module = this;

        this.sortable = Sortable.create(el, {
        onSort: function(e) {
        //module.sortable.sort(module.sortable.toArray());
        vm.items.removeAll();
      }
    });
    }
};
```

When i manipulate the DOM directly as in example jQuery UI sortable or in my case: Sortable (https://github.com/RubaXa/Sortable), the binding is broken.

See my small jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wgv76t25/15/

In this example, after sorting i remove all items from my observable.
You`ll see that the dragged node will not be removed.

Ofcourse the observable list is not representative anymore because the order has changed in the UI. But if i revert it with:

```
module.sortable.sort(module.sortable.toArray());
```

on line 7 then all nodes are disconnected from the observable. Or when i adjust the observable array to the right order, the dragged DOM node is disconnected.

The question is: how can i rebind the observable with UI? I prefer to rebind only the dragged DOM node.
I tried:
- vm.items.valueHasMutated
- ko.cleanNode on the ul and/or the moved li`s
- ko.applyBinding on the ul in combination with cleanNode

The cleanNode and applyBindings attempt, the DOM nodes are duplicated:

```
ko.cleanNode(document.querySelector("#vm ul"));
ko.applyBindings( vm, document.querySelector("#vm ul") );
```

Neither this works:

```
ko.cleanNode(document.querySelector("#vm ul"));
ko.applyBindingsToNode( document.querySelector("#vm ul"), vm );
vm.items.remove(vm.items()[1]);
```

Nothing works so far, hope someone can help me

Comment: This binding works ok for me - https://github.com/SortableJS/knockout-sortablejs

Comment: Did you integrate `knockout-sortablejs` as referenced by @TSV?

Comment: Yes but that library is not quite well. I had to remove 1 line of code, then it works fine. Thank you